# How to get the indexes of contours' array to choose the N largest contours using opencv and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to find the 2 largest contours using python and opencv.

I have tried to get the indexes and then call a drawContour function, but something goes wrong.

This is my code

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(roi, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

largest_area = 0
second_area = 0
l_index = 0
s_index = 0
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv.contourArea(c)
    if (area > largest_area):
        if (area > second_area):
            second_area = largest_area
            largest_area = area
            l_index = i
    elif (area > second_area):
        second_area = area
        s_index = i

cv.drawContours(frame, contours[l_index], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv.imshow('frame',frame)
```

This is the error:

> cv.drawContours(frame, contours[l_index], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
>   IndexError: list index out of range

A second question, if I could make it, I don't know how to draw both of them, how could I do that?

Comment: The logic of finding those 2 largest areas doesn't make much sense. | If `area > largest_area`, then you should `second_area = largest_area` and update the `largest_area` (of course updating the corresponding indices in sync as well). Otherwise, if `area > second_area` you just update the `second_area` (and the corresponding index). | Debug your code. The simplest way is to just add a bunch of `print` statements that show the current state of the variables in question.

Comment: You right!! I just fixed it!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First answer.**

You're using `drawContours` function in a wrong way.
2nd parameter of `drawContours` is a list of `contour`(=a list of `Point`)s and 3rd parameter is the index of the `contour` you want to draw.
So your code should be:

```
cv.drawContours(frame, contours, l_index, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

**Second answer.**

If you want to draw both contours, just call `drawContours` twice.

```
cv.drawContours(frame, contours, l_index, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv.drawContours(frame, contours, s_index, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Even I had read the documentation, I didn't notice it should be placed at the third parameter, thanks, both answer works!